# PASSPORT GOOGLE OAUTH2 WITH TOKENS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, google-oauth

is there a way how can i send tokens after successfull login with passport google oauth and after that access them in react ? I dont want to use cookies. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for Minimal, Reproducible Example for getting better answers from community.